# Reading and writing data from same serial port using pyserial

Tags: python, user-interface, pyserial, serial-communication

So I'm working on a program to simulate a data terminal. The program uses GUI and is required to read the data from the COM port and write to it as well. I've used the `pyserial` library and the read part of the program is correctly implemented.

However, When I attempt to write using the same port, an exception is raised by the library saying the port is not accessible. It should be possible to read and write using the same COM port since it's full duplex, so the problem must lie in the way I'm approaching it. Can anyone shed any light as to how, I can enable the write part of the program as well.

Edit: Here is the traceback of the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                          
  File "C:\Ankit\python_27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner                
    self.run()                                                                              
  File "C:\Ankit\SerWatchCode\serialcomm.py", line 85, in run                               
    self.ser.open()                                                                         
  File "C:\Ankit\python_27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 62, in open       
    raise SerialException("could not open port %r: %r" % (self.portstr, ctypes.WinError())) 
SerialException: could not open port 'COM2': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Have you checked the device permissions?

Comment: Im on Windows 7 and yes I have. The issue appears to be my not closing the read thread before a write is called.

Comment: So write works if you use a single thread? Can you add the exception and traceback to the question. You can try using the port by running `python serial.tools.miniterm` in a terminal. See if you can read and write using that.

Comment: Sure let me get to my office and I'll post it